# Parsing CSV File into Python into a contigous block

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to load in time series/Apple's stock price data (3000X5) into Python. 
So date, open, high, low, close. I am running the following code in python spyder.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import csv

datafile = open('C:\Users\Riemmman\Desktop\SAMPLE_AAPL_DATA_FOR_Python.csv')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
data = []

for row in datareader:
    data.append(row)
```

But the 'data' file still remains as a list file. I want it separated into a continuous block with the headers on top and the data in it's respective column with date being at the utmost left-hand side. As one would see the data in R/Matlab. What am I missing? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to *transpose* the data; rows to columns. The `zip()` function, when applied to all rows, does this for you. Use `*datareader` to have Python pull all rows in and apply them as separate arguments to the `zip()` function:

```
filename = 'C:\Users\Riemmman\Desktop\SAMPLE_AAPL_DATA_FOR_Python.csv'
with open(filename, 'rb') as datafile:
    datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
    columns = zip(*datareader)
```

This also uses some more best practices:

- Using the file as a context manager with the `with` statement ensures it is clsed automatically
- Open the file in binary mode so the `csv` module can manage line endings correctly

Comment: Thanks Martijn! The code you wrote did desperate the variable into these things called tuple?? with each header on top and the value below each. Is there a way though to show entire dataset in an excel spread sheet style in the spyder data viewer? 
The way the data is now formatted is each variable is its own "tuple", 5 tuple's because I have 5 variables. So I have to click into each tuple to see the data

Comment: Sorry; I am not familiar with the Spyder data viewer!

Comment: ok, I see. If I wanted to access the data in the "Columns" variable you created, say for a given Date:"12/31/2013" and variable:"High", how would you access the data? Is it possible to reference row/column?

Comment: @jessica: I don't know what data you have in that file, but it sounds as if you want to access data *by row*, not by column.

Comment: yes! how, I tried "columns[5,3], ie, 5th row, 3rd' row/variable. But its no worky :(

Comment: It is a nested list; use `columns[5][3]` in that case.